# Extracting financial indicator data from trading chart

Tags: graphics, finance

How can the data of the directional movement index below be extracted from this chart?  It seems to be embedded in some kind of dynamic module.

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV",
   {{2013, 12, 31}, {2014, 3, 31}}];
chart = TradingChart[data,
  {FinancialIndicator["AverageDirectionalMovementIndex", 7]},
  Appearance -> "Line"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** You can also use all `FinancialIndicator[...]` functions directly on `data`:

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV", {{2013, 12, 31}, {2014, 3, 31}}];
admi = FinancialIndicator["AverageDirectionalMovementIndex", 7][data]
(* {22.3186, 25.4227, 27.7113, 30.474, 34.1408, 38.1074, 41.6553, 44.6964, 47.9435, 
    51.9707, 55.5629, 55.1122, 52.5314, 45.1471, 38.9678, 37.5043, 37.1767, 34.0487,
    33.8211, 33.626, 35.1984, 36.5461, 38.589, 40.3401, 41.841, 44.0037, 46.6283, 
    49.0705, 47.2018, 49.0292, 51.285, 53.5837, 55.9859, 52.8501, 50.3013, 47.5135, 
    42.8011, 41.419, 35.6862, 33.3807, 29.597, 26.9006, 25.2456, 24.9361, 29.7563, 
    34.0085, 32.7614, 31.3429, 31.3501} *)
```

**2.** Or you can use [Setting](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Setting.html) on your original `chart` and extract the parts you need using `Cases[...]` as in @Kuba's answer:

```
 Cases[Cases[Setting@chart, _Graphics, \[Infinity]][[3]], 
         Line[x_, ___] :> x, {0, \[Infinity]}][[-1]]
 (* {{14., 22.3186}, {15., 25.4227}, {16., 27.7113}, {17., 30.474},
     {18., 34.1408}, {19., 38.1074}, {20., 41.6553}, {21., 44.6964}, 
     {22., 47.9435}, {23., 51.9707}, {24., 55.5629}, {25., 55.1122},
     {26., 52.5314}, {27., 45.1471}, {28., 38.9678}, {29., 37.5043}, 
     {30., 37.1767}, {31., 34.0487}, {32., 33.8211}, {33., 33.626}, 
     {34., 35.1984}, {35., 36.5461}, {36., 38.589}, {37., 40.3401},
     {38., 41.841}, {39., 44.0037}, {40., 46.6283}, {41., 49.0705}, 
     {42., 47.2018}, {43., 49.0292}, {44., 51.285}, {45., 53.5837}, 
     {46., 55.9859}, {47., 52.8501}, {48., 50.3013}, {49., 47.5135}, 
     {50., 42.8011}, {51., 41.419}, {52., 35.6862}, {53., 33.3807},
     {54., 29.597}, {55., 26.9006}, {56., 25.2456}, {57., 24.9361}, 
     {58., 29.7563}, {59., 34.0085}, {60., 32.7614}, {61., 31.3429},
     {62.,  31.3501}} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can suppress those functionalities with `PerformanceGoal`:

```
chart = TradingChart[data, {FinancialIndicator["AverageDirectionalMovementIndex", 7]}, 
         Appearance -> "Line", PerformanceGoal :> "Speed"]
```

and proceed further with `Cases` to extract what you need:

```
Cases[chart, _Graphics, ∞]
```

> [image]

```
Cases[Cases[chart, _Graphics, ∞][[3]], Line[x_, ___] :> x, {0, ∞}][[-1]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Aha! `PerformanceGoal` - Thanks