# Overlay a line plot onto a candlestick chart?

Tags: charts, finance

With the command [`CandlestickChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CandlestickChart.html) one can create charts such as

```
CandlestickChart[data]
```

> [image]

Let's say, we take the 20-period moving average of the closing values of each candle, and store it in a list called `data20MA` with the same `DateObject` time-stamps for the x-axis. How can we display both, the candle stick chart and the 20-period moving average line on top of each other in Mathematica 11.3?
(I tried to `Show` the `CandlestickChart` with a `DateListPlot`, but it produced an erroneous picture.)

EDIT:

Perhaps a moving average is too simple for this question. More generally, if we have a list of values `list` computed for each time stamp of the price data, how can we overlay a `ListLinePlot` (or equivalent) of `list` with a candlestick chart of `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TradingChart` to get the same chart with the added convenience of a hundred built-in indicators:

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV", {{2009, 5, 1}, {2010, 4, 30}}];

Row[{CandlestickChart[data, ImageSize -> Medium], 
  TradingChart[data, {"OHLC"}, ImageSize -> Medium]}]
```

[image]

```
TradingChart[data, {"OHLC", {"SimpleMovingAverage", 20}}, 
 "IndicatorStyle" -> Directive[Thick, Red], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks useful, but I actually referred to the 20-period moving average just for simplicity. What if I have created my own indicator, which would not be built into Mathematica by default. How can I overlay a line from a list of values of a custom indicator onto a candle stick chart?

Comment: @Kagaratsch, set the number `n` to 20 in `{"SimpleMovingAverage", n}`  to take the simple moving average based on previous 20 periods (see ["SimpleMovingAverage"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/indicator/SimpleMovingAverage.html)). Re adding a custom indicator see  [this great answer by Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/232823/125).

Comment: I notice that whenever I put `TradingChart` (or `CandlestickChart`) into a `Dynamic`, the notebook becomes unresponsive, updates to the data displayed on the charts take a whole second to appear and even the mouse becomes laggy. Is there a type of candle stick chart in mathematica that works well with quickly updating dynamic data?